# SmartGWT button listener

Tags: java, smartgwt

I want add handler or listener to button which will respond every time I press key on keyboard even It's not focus on it. How I can do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler;

Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler() {

   @Override
   public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
      if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE) { //needs an int code
         //fire an event to your button or call your method

         event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation(); //optional
         event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault(); //optional
      }
   }
});
```

I was using a code like this in my onModuleLoad() method to catch the a keypress event and hide it from the browser. You can also use the

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;

Element as = (Element) Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
as.getTagName();
```

to check where it is coming from (for example tag name is "input", "textarea"), and do your event handling based on that.

Comment: I use your method in my presenter class but I have a two problem:
1. When I press keyboard my method performed two times;
2. When I add this method I cannot induce my method by click on button by mouse;

Comment: Answers for your questions: 1: you can also get the event.getNativeEvent().getType() and check that too. For a keyboard press it first sends an event with type "keydown" then you will receive a "keyup". So yes, it is called two times minimum, but you can receive it with "keypress" too, when you keep pressing the button. 2. I don't really understand this problem. Your button should have it's own ClickHandler, which will be called if you click on the button by mouse. This solution is for catching keyboard or even mouse actions globally, no matter what is in the focus or target.

Comment: Thanks for your help everything is alright. I have separate ClickHandlers for my buttons but I could not click them I don't know why but now it's ok.